# Downloading a .wav file and storing it in NSFileManager defaultManager returns NULL when accessed [Objective C]

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, wav

I am trying to download a .wav file and store it in `NSFileManager defaultManager`. I have verified the download, storage, and access path and are all the same. However, when I use the access path the value for: `[fileAttributes valueForKey:NSFileSize]` it returns NULL. I am seeing some of the audio attributes displayed on the screen such as the length of the clip, but there is no content when trying to play the audio. See below:

```
NSString *filename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.wav",self.vm.vmid];
NSURL *vmURL = [voicemailDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[vmURL path] error:nil];
NSLog(@"File size: %@", [fileAttributes valueForKey:NSFileSize]);
```

The last log statement displays: `File size: (null)`. Further code then proceeds to tell me that the audio file does not exist: `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[vmURL path]]`. But again, I have other attributes displayed on the screen that would suggest otherwise.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**

Added an error log:

fileAttributes now throws this error:
`fileAttributes error :: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “<audioFile>.wav” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=<path>/<audioFile>.wav, NSUnderlyingError=0x174254f10 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}`

However, when I display the contents of `NSFileManger defaultManger` the `<audioFile>.wav` is displayed as though it exists and is stored.

Comment: Is `fileAttributes` nil? Make use of the `error` parameter so you know what the problem is.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for the suggestion, I have added the error message code and the displayed message has been added above.

Comment: Were these displayed attributes retrieves while the `wav` file was in your memory (before saving the file) or after it has been saved? Because it might be a permissions problem while saving the file locally.